# How to determine whether a given string is an .xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have an issue that I get some some response as a String.
This String could be a normal string,number etc.. or an .xml file.

Now ,when I get an xml file, I want to treat it differently.
I am not able to distinguish between a string or an .xml file.
Also, this xml file could have some syntatic error.

Please suggest , how do I go ahead

Code is like this:

```
Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));
```

where xml can be a string or an xml file itself.
If xml is a string , it is fine but if it is an xml file and with some syntax error then it  should throw exception

Comment: Do you mean the content of the string can be an XML document?

Comment: The code is like this Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));  , where xml is a string

Comment: _Edit_ the question and add the code to the question, not in comments.

Comment: Yes, for example  "xml" can be an .xml file or a normal string like "Hello"

Comment: What language is that? What is a `Document`? And please note the difference between a `.xml` file and an XML document. The first is a file with a certain extension, the second a string following a certain format.

Comment: This is JAVA  Document is org.dom4j.Document;

Comment: yes larsmans in this scenario the content is an xml file which is a string and not ".xml" file itself

Comment: It looks like a very poor design. Using the same variable to hold either the content of an XML document or a URI pointing to the document can only lead to trouble. But if you need to tell which it is, then parsing it as a URI (using new URI()) should tell you the answer (so would parsing it as an XML document, but that's probably more expensive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a proper XML document it should begin with a [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-XMLDecl).  If that's there, it's intended to be a conforming XML document.  If that's not there it cannot be a conforming XML document.

Comment: The XML declaration is optional in XML documents, so this is **not** a reliable method to tell if the file contains XML. Besides, the file could be in different encodings (e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE) and might or might not start with a byte order mark (BOM) character. An XML parser handles all these variations. So it is simpler to just try to parse it as XML and see if that fails, rather than try to write your own tests for XML (and correctly handling all the possible cases).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a coding language like C#, then you can use - **XmlDocument.loadxml** -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

This will throw error if the string is not in correct xml format.